# Очередность действий UIButton

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток! У меня (опять) возникла проблема, которую я даже не представляю как решить.
Ситуация такая: есть кнопка (стандартная UIButton), которая выполняет два действия: устанавливает значение ключа в NSUserDefaults и выполняет переход на другой View Controller (через Storyboard Segue). На этом втором View Controller'е есть изображение, которое меняется в зависимости от ключа. Проблема в том, что таких кнопок у меня несколько, некоторые работают корректно: нажал кнопку - открылся другой View Controller с изображением, которое пользователь выбрал нажатием кнопки. А другие кнопки сначала открывают контроллер, а потом уже меняют значение ключа, из-за чего картинка меняется только со второго раза. Как можно изменить порядок действий кнопки?
Спасибо за помощь. Всех с наступающим!

Comment: @Ruslan_T Покажите весь код который отвечает за переход и отображение VC. Всю цепочку.

Comment: Переход на второй View Controller осуществляется у меня не кодом, а Segue, который я сделал зажатием кнопки Contol, так что кода для перехода я и не писал.

Comment: @Ruslan_T Тогда где у вас происходит изменение  ключа?

Comment: Если открыть настройки кнопки, там у меня такое:
acton -> present modally  View Controller

Touch Up Inside -> View Controller changeImageButton

Второе связано с таким кодом в ViewController.m:

    - (IBAction)changeImageButton:(id)sender
    {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    [defaults setObject:@"wallpaper.png" forKey:@"Theme"];
    
    [defaults synchronize];
    }

Comment: Загружается изображение так:

    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    NSString *result = [defaults objectForKey:@"Theme"];
    
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:(NSString *)result];
    
    self.backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage;
}

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @Ruslan_T, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри контроллера с кнопками реализуйте метод
`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` 
вместо представленных вами `changeImageButton:` и `viewDidLoad`.
Если `NSUserDefaults` был нужен только для передачи значения, то можете убрать его из этого действия.